# CSS - SVG issue

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image:

[image]

This is what I am doing to display the iamge:

```
background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
background-image: url(a.svg);
```

This is the result:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#a {
  background-color: rgb(56, 46, 36);
  height: 80px;
}
#b {
  justify-content: center;
}
#b a {
  color: rgb(100, 90, 80);
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
#b a:hover,
#b a.active {
  background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
  background-image: url(https://imgh.us/a_8.svg);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" class="flex">
  <a href="#">O nás</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">Fotogaléria</a>
  <a href="#">Denné menu</a>
  <a href="#">Jedálny lístok</a>
  <a href="#">Ubytovanie</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
</div>
```

Can you tell me how to stretch the SVG to 100%?

The result I expected:

[image: Required result]

Here is demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az5e1o8q)

Comment: Please share a working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you create a demo of the issue?

Comment: If I've understood correctly, `div.svg-logo svg { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rvervuurt - http://jsfiddle.net/az5e1o8q/

Comment: I felt generous today and i have faced the same problem, so i edited the question so its easier to understand the problem and added code from the  fiddle.

Comment: probably this can be work  **#b a:hover, #b a.active {
    background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
    background: url(http://imgh.us/a_8.svg) 100%;
    color: #fff;
}** pls check out

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara thats an answer not a comment. It looks good. If you explain the background shorthand in your answer i'll even upvote it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the background-size to cover it will fill it to its width. (since your image is taller then wide).

Adding `background-position: bottom;` makes it so that this particular image will always be displayed.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#a {
  background-color: rgb(56, 46, 36);
  height: 480px;
}
#b {
  justify-content: center;
}
#b a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgb(100, 90, 80);
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
#b a:hover,
#b a.active {
  background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/a_8.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="b" class="flex">
  <a href="#">O nás</a>
  <a href="#">Fotogaléria</a>
  <a href="#">Denné menu</a>
  <a href="#">Jedálny lístok</a>
  <a href="#">Ubytovanie</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS as follows:

```
#b a:hover, #b a.active {
    background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
    background-image: url("http://imgh.us/a_8.svg");
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

You need the `background-size 100% 100%` to fill the background in all directions (especially on narrower elements), but it does affect your transition a little.

Comment: Can you send me a link to JSFiddle? I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's linked already ... sorry if I made it less obvious - click "It works"

Answer (score 0):

actually i have done is that i just only given the background as image only to the 100%

now what happens is that i used **background** property so it will override the **background-color** automatically while background is **repeating due to 100%**

even you can give it by **repeat** to the background here is what i have done and it looks good isn't it.?

```css
#b a:hover, #b a.active {
  background-color: rgb(110, 100, 90);
  background: url(http://imgh.us/a_8.svg) 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: @Persijn hi updated as an answer and explained what it is